# Android camera error in Samsung Galaxy J7

Tags: camera

Got a Samsung Galaxy J7 and one day all of a sudden the back camera started throwing an error. When I try to open the camera, it displays a popup saying "Camera Error". How can I track this error? The phone is not rooted by the way. I've already factory reset the phone.

Comment: If you have performed a factory reset and the error stays, then most likely the error is caused by a hardware defect.

Comment: Brand new camera. :(

Comment: So the camera was replaced by a repair shop (you totally forgot to tell us this important little detail)? After being replaced was the camera working at least once?

Comment: Not even once..

Comment: If it never worked then the replacement camera may be defect, not matching the phone, or some other hardware failure is present. Why have you replaced the old camera, was it non-functional (with the same error) or just bad quality? When replacing parts a lot of thing can break (the flat wires, the connectors, or some of the connected chips, ...).

Comment: The old one was with the same error, but even before when it was working, the lens broke and there was water infiltration, so the camera image was kinda weird, after some time it started throwing that error. I've replaced the camera with one announced for the very phone model, it didn't work, I've reset the phone and here we are.

Comment: It's an hardware problem, clearly. And all the info you've provided in comments should be in the question itself.